# Should you hyphenate 'one hour session'?

Tags: grammatical-number, hyphenation

The phrase *two-hour session* should have a hyphen, because you are making a singular of what is actually plural, i.e. two hours.
But what about a *one hour* session? Should that be '*one-hour* session'?

Comment: I don't think two-hour has a hyphen because it is actually plural but because it describes the session as would be the case with one-hour session.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are making an adjective out of the words one and hour, you should hyphenate. The combination of one and hour modifies the word session.

[See a quick link here](https://briandbuckley.com/2012/02/29/three-grammar-mistakes-smart-people-still-make/)

[And the Chicago style manual here, in particular page two](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/images/ch07_tab01.pdf)